# Perl ithreads :shared variables - multiprocessor kernel threads - visibility

Tags: multithreading, perl, multiprocessor, memory-visibility

perlthrtut excerpt:

> Note that a shared variable guarantees that if two or more threads try
>   to modify it at the same time, the internal state of the variable will
>   not become corrupted. However, there are no guarantees beyond this, as
>   explained in the next section.

Working on Linux supporting multiprocessor kernel threads.

Is there a guarantee that all threads will see the updated shared variable value ?
Consulting the perlthrtut doc as stated above there is no such guarantee.

Now the question: What can be done programmatically to guarantee that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask

> *Is there a guarantee that all threads will see the updated shared variable value ?*

Yes.  `:shared` is that guarantee.  The value will be safely and consistently and freshly updated.

The problem is simply that, without other synchronization, you don't know the order of these updates.

> *Consulting the perlthrtut doc as stated above there is no such guarantee.*

You didn't read far enough. :)

The very next section in [perlthrtut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html) explains the kind of pitfalls you *do* face with perl threads:  data races, which is to say, application logic races concerning shared data.  Again, the shared data will be consistent and fresh and immune to corruption from (more-or-less) atomic perl opcodes.  However, the high-level perl operations you perform on that shared data are *not* guaranteed to be atomic.  `$shared_var++`, for instance, might be more than one atomic operation.

(If I may hazard a guess, you are perhaps thinking too much about other languages' lower level threading interfaces with their cache inconsistencies, torn words, reordered instructions, and lions and tigers and bears.  Perl's model takes care of those low-level concerns for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `:shared` on a variable causes all threads to reference it in the **same physical memory address**, so it doesn't matter which processor/core/hyper-thread they happen to be executing in. The `perlthrtut` talk of *guarantees* is in reference to race conditions, and in short, that you need to take into account that shared variables can be modified by any thread at any time. If this is a problem you'll need to make use of synchronization functions (e.g. `lock()` and `cond_wait()`) to control access.

Comment: The "same physical memory address" is a bit of a simplification.  Different threads will show different values for the address of a shared variable, for instance.  The same physical address doesn't address concerns of cache consistency, which I suspect may be part of the OP's concern.

Comment: Perl creates a separate thread to gate access to variables then uses ties to access the data from the other threads. When you see a different address on a shared variable it's from the tie. And cache consistency is really out of the scope of perl and in the realm of CPU/chipset design. As programmers it should be safe to assume that our system is MPS compliant, no?

Comment: Yes, I know, and your comment conveys a precision that your initial statement did not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit new here and have not built up the intuition to know when an answer has enough information without going overboard.

Comment: No problem.  I think the OP's understanding of other environment's threading might be (dis)coloring his understanding of perl's threading semantics.  So, I think he needs either excruciating implementation details or just high level semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused as to what `:shared` does. It makes it so a variable is shared by all threads.

A variable is indeed guaranteed to have the value it has, no matter which thread accesses it. It's a tautology, so nothing can be done to programmatically guarantee that.

Comment: perlthrtut is not confirming your statement, to me this is rather an opinion